# log4j2 logging to console only

Tags: java, log4j2, rollingfileappender

I have a maven web project which requires logging.

I decided to use log4j2 for that purpose and added the required entries in the `pom.xml` file

Then I created the `log4j2.xml` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${logs.path}/text.log"
            filePattern="${logs.path}/%d{YYYYMMdd}-text.%i.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5p %c{1}:%L - %msg%n" />
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20" />
        </RollingFile>

        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="root" level="info" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" level="info" />
            <appender-ref ref="Console" level="info" />
        </Logger>
        <Root level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I'm starting tomcat with `-Dlogs.path="C:\mylogs"`, where `C:\mylogs` exists and has public read/write access.

The console logger is working fine, I can see the correct output in my console, the issue is that the file isn't being created, so I have no logfile, everything gets logged to `catalina.out` only, and the tomcat startup logs don't show errors for log4j.

What am I missing? is there some additional configuration I need to do in order to log to file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through the [documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#PropertySubstitution). You must refer to system properties with `sys:`, and it seems that tomcat properties are seen as system properties, so I replaced `${logs.path}` with `${sys:logs.path}` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

To create a log file with the log4j2 config you first need to define your appender. Here's an example:

```
<RollingFile name="MGMT"
                 fileName="${logdir}/mgmt.log"
                 filePattern="${logdir}/mgmt.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
      <PatternLayout pattern="${layout}"/>
      <CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0 0 0 * * ?"/>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        <Delete basePath="${logdir}" maxDepth="1">
          <IfFileName glob="mgmt.*.log" />
          <IfAccumulatedFileCount exceeds="10" />
        </Delete>
      </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
    </RollingFile>
```

Afterwards you just need to define a logger that will use it:

```
<Logger name="the package or name that is displayed in the log line"
            level="ALL"
            additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="MGMT"/>
    </Logger>
```

If you have a log that has `com.company.test` as package set that package as name for the logger. **It's important that they match.**

The field `additivity` will define if you want to pass the catched log to its parent ( true ) or just let this logger handle it ( false )

EDIT:

your config file might need this:

```
<Configuration status="info">
  <Properties>
    <Property name="logdir">${sys:catalina.base}/logs</Property>
    <Property name="layout">%d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n</Property>
  </Properties>
  <Appenders>
```

If you don't want to use this you have to define the path static like `<RollingFile name="MGMT"
   fileName="C:\path\file.log"`

Comment: @BackSlash so you're saying that you have a log having root in it?
If I have a log line like this: `2017-06-06 15:16:14,997 [Thread-6] DEBUG ProcessUtils- starting process: [checkState.cmd]` I have to add `<Logger name="ProcessUtils" level="xx"...></Logger>`

Comment: I have a root level logger which should log everything, regardless of the package/class name.

Comment: @BackSlash Now I see where the problem might be. Did you define the properties or did you just delete them? I will edit my answer and please verify

Comment: I didn't define properties, I don't use them so I didn't define them. The only property I use is `${logs.path}` which is a tomcat property and should be available to log4j too.